# Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions<Seller>'

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node-mongodb-native, node.js-typeorm

Using **mongodb** by **typeorm** with **nestjs** - create crud rest api

When trying to get data by **findone()** with '**id**' . getting below error

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'FindOneOptions'.

Code:

```
 const result = await this.sellerRepository.findOne({ id });
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity('seller')
export class Seller {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  id: ObjectID;
  @Column({
    type: 'string',
    nullable: false,
    name: 'product_name',
  })
  productName: string;
  @Column({
    name: 'short_desc',
  })
}

async findOne(id: string): Promise<Seller> {
    const result = await this.sellerRepository.findOne({ id });
    return result;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It's being discussed on github at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for above..

I used `new ObjectID(id)` and
`import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';`

if you get error like **TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'mongodb'**

then follow below steps

1. create folder with 'typings'any at root project
2. create index.d.ts
3. add `declare module 'mongodb'`;
4. add path of the `index.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json` file under
   `typeRoots` as below

`"typeRoots": [ "./typings", "./node_modules/@types/" ]`

sample code

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
 async findOne(id: string): Promise<Seller> {
    const result = await this.sellerRepository.findOne(new ObjectID(id));
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [findOneBy](https://typeorm.io/find-options)

```
findOne(id: number): Promise<User> {
   return this.usersRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });
}
```

Comment: Already tried with the above but did not work. It gives the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fithOneBy({id})` or `findOne(id)`. The signature you provided does not match any method provided by TypeORM, so that's why Typescript complains.

You can always check all available options [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options) and [here](https://typeorm.io/).

Comment: Both tried but there is no use. I think  typeorm  gives this kind of error for mongodb

Comment: Are you sure the error remains the same?

Comment: yes..but got solution in another way..will post it...thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

You can use exported types from 'typeorm' like this:

```
import { FindOptionsWhere } from 'typeorm';
```

...

```
const result = await this.sellerRepository.findOne({ id: id as FindOptionsWhere<Seller> });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```js
const prodId = await this.productEntity.findOne({
  where: {
    column_name_in_Entity: defined initializer
  }
})
```